# Stepping Through Array & Returning Matched/Non-Matched Value in Array Based on Search Term

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

In my `searchForANumber` method, I'm trying to display if a number is found within my array or not. The problem is, I'm using and `if, else` to determine if the `searchValue` matches a value in the array statement in my for loop, and when I do this, the last variable in the array is tested, and my returned value is based on only the final value. How can I make so that my return phrase is based on all elements in the array and not just the last one? Do I use a while, do-while, switch loop? Any help is appreciated.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

public class Practice {
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter your minimum number: ");
    int minNumber = input.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Enter your maximum number: ");
    int maxNumber = input.nextInt();

    int[] array = new int[(maxNumber-minNumber)+1];
    int[]readInArray = new int[maxNumber-minNumber+1];

    readInArray=readNumbers(minNumber, maxNumber, array);

    printNumbers(readInArray, minNumber);

    searchForANumber(readInArray, minNumber);

    sumNumbers(readInArray);

    printBackward(readInArray);


}//end of main method

private static void printBackward(int[] readInArray) {
    for (int i=(readInArray.length-1);i>0;i--){
        System.out.print(readInArray[i] + " ");
    }

}

private static void sumNumbers(int[] readInArray) {
    int total = 0;
    for (int i=0;i<readInArray.length;i++){

        total = total + readInArray[i];
    }
    System.out.println(total);

}

private static void searchForANumber(int[] readInArray, int minNumber) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter number to search for: ");
    int searchValue = input.nextInt();
    boolean returnValue = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < readInArray.length;i++) {
        if (searchValue == readInArray[i])
            returnValue=true;
            break;

    }// end of for
    System.out.println(returnValue);

}

private static void printNumbers(int[] readInArray, int minNumber) {
    for (int i = 0; i < readInArray.length;i++) {
        System.out.print(readInArray[i] + " ");
        minNumber++;
    }
    System.out.println(" ");

}

private static int[] readNumbers(int minNumber, int maxNumber, int[] array) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length;i++) {// input grades for each students
        array[i]=minNumber;
        minNumber++;
    } // end of for loop

    return array;
} // end of readArray method

}//end of class
```

Comment: Why not return a `boolean`?

Comment: Can you post your searchForANumber(...) method?

Comment: It's posted, you just need to scroll down

Comment: Try initializing returnValue to false, and if you do find what you're looking for, set returnValue to true and break out of the loop.

Comment: @user1813598 I made the suggested revision, and I still get the same errors sadly.  `boolean returnValue = false;
  for (int i = 0; i < readInArray.length;i++) {
   if (searchValue == readInArray[i])
    returnValue=true;
    break;`

Comment: did you put curly braces around the "returnValue = true; break;" statements?  As in, do you have "if (searchValue == readInArray[i]) { returnValue = true; break; }"

Answer (score 0):

you can do it in two ways.

1. make your method `searchForANumber` return boolean.

   ```
   private static boolean searchForANumber(int[] readInArray, int minNumber) {
   //before for loop
   for (int i = 0; i < readInArray.length;i++) {
       if (searchValue == readInArray[i])
           return true;
       }
   return false;
   }
   ```
2. use `break` and a `boolean`

   ```
   private static void searchForANumber(int[] readInArray, int minNumber) {
   //before for loop
   boolean found = false;
   for (int i = 0; i < readInArray.length;i++) {
       if (searchValue == readInArray[i]){
          found = true;
          break;
         }
       }
   if(found)
    System.out.println("Found");
   else
    System.out.println("Not Found");
   }
   ```